# Need to load the UI5 Module from Other Host in SAP Fiori

Tags: tomcat, custom-controls, sapui5, sap-fiori

We have 2 applications one is SAP Fiori App which is deployed in SAP ABAP repository and another app which is written OpenUI5 which is not related to SAP so we have deployed in Apache Tomcat.

We need to Integrate these 2 applications like on clicking of a button in Fiori app need to open the OpenUI5 app.

Problem is the Module (App) Which is deployed on Tomcat is not able open because when we registerModulePath the domian is not taking by Fiori

```
    jQuery.sap.addUrlWhitelist("http", "tomcat.server.host", "7070", "/tomcatapp/resources/js/ui5widgets");

    jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("com.xxx.yyy", "http://tomcat.server.host:7070/tomcatapp/resources/js/ui5widgets");
```

when i require

error is

```
core-min-0-dbg.js:17351 Uncaught Error: failed to load 'com/xxx/yyy/aaa/bbb.js' from /sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/resources/~20151006101200~/com/xxx/yyy/aaa/bbb.js: 

0 - AbortError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://sap.netweaver.net:2020/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/resources/~20151006101200~/com/xxx/yyy/aaa/bbb.js'.(…)
```

Comment: You are not overridding an existing package name by any chance?

Comment: no, i am using same package names

Comment: Does the path of 'com/xxx/yyy/aaa/bbb.js' get resolved correctly if you use a relative path? I just wonder why it fails to load from 'http://sap.netweaver.net:2020/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/resources/~20151006101200~/com/xxx/yyy/aaa/bbb.js' which is not the path you registered.

Comment: the 'com/xxx/yyy/aaa/bbb.js' in not deployed in the 'sap.netweaver.net:2020' its in tomcat server.

Comment: I understood that. Could you anyways temporarily register it under a relative path just to see if the path com.xxx.yyy.aaa.bbb resolves correctly under that circumstances?

Comment: i have deployed a new BSP Application and deployed to it.. i need to do these `jQuery.sap.registerResourcePath("com.xxx.yyy", '/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/tomcat_app/');
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("com.xxx.yyy", '/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/tomcat_app/');
jQuery.sap.require("com.xxx.yyy.aaa.bbb");`

Comment: and if you run this and open network tab from where does it try to load com.xxx.yyy.aaa.bbb?!

Comment: http://sap.netweaver.net:2020/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/~260E5717C4F9E3BA7C7E1EFFB42F115E~C/sap/tomcat_app/aaa/bbb.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("test.test", "http://www.google.de");
jQuery.sap.require("test.test.MyTest");
```

The file is correctly resolved to http://www.google.de/MyTest.js.

Are you sure that your package name is not overridden by something else? e.g. a package name like 'sap.ui.something' will obviously be a bad idea. But there are less obvious examples. May be you show a little more/real code?

Anyways you will have to take care of [CORS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)

Comment: @chiranjeevigk I don't quite get how this solved your problem but thanks for accepting anyways ;)